# Handling the null value from a resultset

Tags: java, jdbc

I currently have a result set returned, and in one of the columns the string value may be null (I mean no values at all). I have a condition to implement like following

```
rs = st.executeQuery(selectSQL);
output = rs.getString("column");
```

Since the column may be null in the database, the `rs.getString()`  will throw a `NullPointerException` when the column is null.  If column is null, I want the output to be an empty string like `output = "";`. I can't check `if(rs.getString("column) != null` either. How can I tackle this situation?

My real problem:

```
try {
    rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
    int i = 0;
    while (rs.next()) {
        output[i] = rs.getString(column);
        // column field in the database contains multiple results, but sometimes
        // may be null
        i++;
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    // other than tracing the exception i want to fill the array too
}
return output;
```

Now, if one of the column values contains no value, i.e. null, I want `output[i]` defined as N/A. This problem stems from the fact that the `column` field is NULL allowed in the database. And sorry for telling you that it's a NPE, while in fact it's a `SQLException`.

Comment: If the column is null, the ResultSet should return null.  Are you sure the ResultSet is not null?

Comment: normally, you can call the `wasNull()` method. I don't see why an NPE would be thrown here.

Comment: `while(rs.next()){ rs.getX(); }`

Comment: I'm decidedly curious as to why this was downvoted.

Answer (score 71):

> Since the column may be null in the
>   database, the rs.getString() will
>   throw a NullPointerException()

No.

`rs.getString` will not throw `NullPointer` if the column is present in the selected result set (SELECT query columns)
For a particular record if value for the 'comumn is null in db, you must do something like this -

```
String myValue = rs.getString("myColumn");
if (rs.wasNull()) {
    myValue = ""; // set it to empty string as you desire.
}
```

You may want to refer to `wasNull()` documentation -

```
From java.sql.ResultSet
boolean wasNull() throws SQLException;

* Reports whether
* the last column read had a value of SQL <code>NULL</code>.
* Note that you must first call one of the getter methods
* on a column to try to read its value and then call
* the method <code>wasNull</code> to see if the value read was
* SQL <code>NULL</code>.
*
* @return <code>true</code> if the last column value read was SQL
*         <code>NULL</code> and <code>false</code> otherwise
* @exception SQLException if a database access error occurs or this method is 
*            called on a closed result set
*/
```

Comment: thank you d-live very much....that solves my problem....chris guided me that it couldn't be a NPE (so i checked again and it was not)...Peter suggested me a suggestion similar to yours but i couldn't understand him previously. But i do now :-)Thanks to all of the guys for helping me...I'm really overwhelemed that the guys here were so quick in replying...i could solve the problem in just a few minutes.

Comment: Glad that it solves your problem! Please accept an answer you find appropriate!

Comment: Why wasn't this answer picked for 5 years @javaNOob?

Comment: @CaioIglesias Because this seems to be his only question and he left after his problem was solved... What, obviously is not the right way to do so....

Answer (score 28):

```
output = rs.getString("column");// if data is null `output` would be null, so there is no chance of NPE unless `rs` is `null`

if(output == null){// if you fetched null value then initialize output with blank string
  output= "";
}
```

Comment: This is a better answer than the above "rs.wasNull()" which is not applicable for every case.

Comment: This works! Thanks! if rs.getString("column") == null {//whatever}

Answer (score 8):

The description of the getString() method says the following:

```
 the column value; if the value is SQL NULL, the value returned is null
```

That means your problem is not that the String value is null, rather some other
object is, perhaps your ResultSet or maybe you closed the connection or something
like this. Provide the stack trace, that would help.

Comment: yes perfectly...I think you understand what i am trying to say. Since rs.getString(col) returns the null when column is infact database null, an exception is thrown instantly. I want to check that when the column is database null(i.e. getString() returns null), output[i] is assigned N/A(but for me empty string "" is also acceptable)

Comment: For rs.getString() you can use the null comparison, but when you have database columns that don't allow null (e.g. rs.getInt()), then you have to use rs.wasNull().

Answer (score 4):

I was able to do this:

```
String a;
if(rs.getString("column") != null)
{
    a = "Hello world!";
}
else
{
    a = "Bye world!";
}
```

Comment: works well, but does not work for rs.getInt() as it returns a primitive (0 by default).  rs.wasNull should be used

Comment: @BojanPetkovic, the question is specifically asking about `getString`. You are basing your response on `getInt`.

Answer (score 2):

The String being null is a very good chance, but when you see values in your table, yet a null is printed by the ResultSet, it might mean that the connection was closed before the value of ResultSet was used.

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:My_db.db");
String sql = ("select * from cust where cust_id='" + cus + "'");
pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
rs = pst.executeQuery();
con.close();
System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
```

Would print `null` even if there are values.

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:My_db.db");
String sql = ("select * from cust where cust_id='" + cus + "'");
pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
rs = pst.executeQuery();
System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
con.close();
```

Wouldn't print `null` if there are values in the table.

Answer (score 0):

The code should be like given below

```
String selectSQL = "SELECT IFNULL(tbl.column, \"\") AS column FROM MySQL_table AS tbl";
Statement st = ...;
Result set rs = st.executeQuery(selectSQL);
```

Answer (score -1):

To treat validation when a field is null in the database, you could add the following condition.

```
String name = (oRs.getString ("name_column"))! = Null? oRs.getString ("name_column"): "";
```

with this you can validate when a field is null and do not mark an exception.

Answer (score -1):

I came across with the same issue. But I believe , handling null in the sql is not a good option. such things should be handled in java program for better performance.
secondly , rs.getString("column") != NULL is also not a good option as you are comparing string's reference not value. better to use .equals() method while checking null or isEmpty() method. Again, with this you can use null check, that is  fine.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use-

```
rs = st.executeQuery(selectSQL);
output = rs.getString("column");
if(!output.isEmpty()) {
 //
}
```

In MySQL faced issue with-

```
output!=null
output!=""
```

**But output.isEmpty() worked for rs.getString().**

Comment: This will throw a `NullPointerException` when `output` is null.